# Manipulate the dataset of time

Tags: r, matrix, time, real-time-data

I have this kind of data set, I want to manipulate it a bit for my own purpose.
The data now is like this:

```
   date  time tmpc
```

> 1. 2019-01-01 00:15 3.11
> 2. 2019-01-01 00:35 3.22
> 3. 2019-01-01 00:55 3.28
> 4. 2019-01-01 01:15 3.28
> 5. 2019-01-01 01:35 3.28
> 6. 2019-01-01 01:55 3.28

(Note that there are 3 columns: date, time and tmpc (temperature)(the observation/values recorded). The time is intraday of every 20 mins in a day. And the date is the dates in 2019).

I want to update this data into another data set/or a matrix with columns as the time (so 72 columns in total) and the rows as the date (so 365 rows in total) and the values (observation of temperature fall exactly as the date and the time as it is recorded). Could anyone have any idea how to do this in R? Thank you in advance.

I tried to create a matrix for it

```
a = matrix (data= NA, nrow = 365, ncol = 72)
colnames(a) = c("00:15", "00:35", "00:55", "01:15", "01:35", "01:55",
      "02:15", "02:35", "02:55", "03:15", "03:35", "03:55",
       "04:15", "04:35", "04:55", "05:15", "05:35", "05:55",
       "06:15", "06:35", "06:55", "07:15", "07:35", "07:55",
       "08:15", "08:35", "08:55", "09:15", "09:35", "09:55",
       "10:15", "10:35", "10:55", "11:15", "11:35", "11:55",
       "12:15", "12:35", "12:55", "13:15", "13:35", "13:55",
       "14:15", "14:35", "14:55", "15:15", "15:35", "15:55",
       "16:15", "16:35", "16:55", "17:15", "17:35", "17:55",
       "18:15", "18:35", "18:55", "19:15", "19:35", "19:55",
       "20:15", "20:35", "20:55", "21:15", "21:35", "21:55",
       "22:15", "22:35", "22:55", "23:15", "23:35", "23:55")
rownames(a) = c(seq.Date(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2019-12-31"), by = "day")
```

It somehows turns out that the rows do not appear as dates as I wanted. It appears as numbers e.g. 17897, 17898, 17899 , etc.  And I intended next to use for loop to input the observation for replace the NA value in exactly date and time as in the original data, however, not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a `data.frame` or coerce the dates to character before making them rownames.

## date frame method

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dates <- seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2019-12-31"), by = "day")
times <- c("00:15", "00:35", "00:55", "01:15", "01:35", "01:55",
           "02:15", "02:35", "02:55", "03:15", "03:35", "03:55",
           "04:15", "04:35", "04:55", "05:15", "05:35", "05:55",
           "06:15", "06:35", "06:55", "07:15", "07:35", "07:55",
           "08:15", "08:35", "08:55", "09:15", "09:35", "09:55",
           "10:15", "10:35", "10:55", "11:15", "11:35", "11:55",
           "12:15", "12:35", "12:55", "13:15", "13:35", "13:55",
           "14:15", "14:35", "14:55", "15:15", "15:35", "15:55",
           "16:15", "16:35", "16:55", "17:15", "17:35", "17:55",
           "18:15", "18:35", "18:55", "19:15", "19:35", "19:55",
           "20:15", "20:35", "20:55", "21:15", "21:35", "21:55",
           "22:15", "22:35", "22:55", "23:15", "23:35", "23:55")
out <- tibble(dates) %>%
  expand(dates, times) %>%
  mutate(values = NA_integer_) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = times, 
              values_from = values)
out
#> # A tibble: 365 x 73
#>    dates      `00:15` `00:35` `00:55` `01:15` `01:35` `01:55` `02:15` `02:35`
#>    <date>       <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
#>  1 2019-01-01      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
#>  2 2019-01-02      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
#>  3 2019-01-03      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
#>  4 2019-01-04      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
#>  5 2019-01-05      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
#>  6 2019-01-06      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
#>  7 2019-01-07      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
#>  8 2019-01-08      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
#>  9 2019-01-09      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
#> 10 2019-01-10      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
#> # i 355 more rows
#> # i 64 more variables: `02:55` <int>, `03:15` <int>, `03:35` <int>,
#> #   `03:55` <int>, `04:15` <int>, `04:35` <int>, `04:55` <int>, `05:15` <int>,
#> #   `05:35` <int>, `05:55` <int>, `06:15` <int>, `06:35` <int>, `06:55` <int>,
#> #   `07:15` <int>, `07:35` <int>, `07:55` <int>, `08:15` <int>, `08:35` <int>,
#> #   `08:55` <int>, `09:15` <int>, `09:35` <int>, `09:55` <int>, `10:15` <int>,
#> #   `10:35` <int>, `10:55` <int>, `11:15` <int>, `11:35` <int>, ...
```

## matrix method

```
a <- matrix(rep_len(NA_integer_, length(dates) * length(times)), 
            nrow = length(dates), ncol = length(times))
 rownames(a) <- as.character(dates)
 colnames(a) <- times
 a[1:5, 1:5]
#>            00:15 00:35 00:55 01:15 01:35
#> 2019-01-01    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#> 2019-01-02    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#> 2019-01-03    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#> 2019-01-04    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#> 2019-01-05    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyr` (included in `tidyverse`) you can use `pivot_wider` and `pivot_longer` to switch between "long" and "wide" data formats

```
> library(tidyverse)
> pivot_wider(df, names_from = time, values_from = tmpc)

# A tibble: 365 × 73
   date      `00:15` `00:35` `00:55` `01:15` `01:35` `01:55` `02:15` `02:35` `02:55` `03:15` `03:35` `03:55` `04:15`
   <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 2019-01-…  0.933  0.00883 9.19e-1   0.299   0.193   0.663   0.103   0.157  0.996   0.578    0.388   0.206  0.961 
 2 2019-01-…  0.835  0.598   3.26e-2   0.972   0.948   0.488   0.146   0.209  0.535   0.0119   0.944   0.472  0.0274
 3 2019-01-…  0.156  0.583   6.62e-1   0.908   0.606   0.741   0.855   0.984  0.936   0.976    0.593   0.458  0.802 
 4 2019-01-…  0.873  0.652   2.71e-4   0.557   0.959   0.615   0.212   0.368  0.0143  0.492    0.555   0.208  0.486 
 5 2019-01-…  0.506  0.515   3.44e-1   0.267   0.864   0.178   0.504   0.370  0.259   0.655    0.124   0.803  0.287 
 6 2019-01-…  0.832  0.971   4.10e-3   0.880   0.549   0.670   0.955   0.291  0.380   0.718    0.877   0.327  0.609 
 7 2019-01-…  0.425  0.820   5.88e-1   0.847   0.555   0.814   0.112   0.203  0.426   0.0660   0.850   0.691  0.649 
 8 2019-01-…  0.0367 0.859   2.75e-1   0.409   0.892   0.142   0.564   0.352  0.634   0.0182   0.116   0.519  0.644 
 9 2019-01-…  0.494  0.891   3.08e-1   0.592   0.305   0.727   0.780   0.370  0.347   0.138    0.508   0.238  0.885 
10 2019-01-…  0.473  0.841   7.39e-1   0.474   0.993   0.994   0.220   0.557  0.918   0.248    0.351   0.574  0.692 
# … with 355 more rows, and 59 more variables: ...
```

#### DATA

```
# creating your example data in "long" format
> library(tidyverse)
> df <- tibble(datetime = seq.POSIXt(from = ymd_hm("2019-01-01 00:15"), 
                                     to   = ymd_hm("2020-01-01 00:00"), 
                                     by   = 20*60)) %>% 
    mutate(date = format(datetime, "%Y-%m-%d"), 
           time = format(datetime, "%H:%M"), 
           tmpc = runif(26280)) %>% 
    select(-datetime)
```